# How do I get my dead guide to respawn?

Tags: terraria

My guide died about the third day I had the game. I thought that having him dead was no problem.

Here I am 1 month later, now ready to face the WoF but there is no guide.

I have made sure my house has met his requirements, but I still don't know how to get him to respawn. I have tried changing my house completely; I have made sure there are no other NPCs; I have gone around the whole map to make sure there was no goblin still alive.

Comment: Is your house near corruption or crimson? Does the house say that it is suitable housing using the housing tool? Check your map, if you've gone to a skybase you may have put a torch inside the room which would make it valid housing which means your guide may be up there. What do you mean by you've made sure that there are no other NPC's?

Comment: To clarify, this is a duplicate because there is no other requirement. Of you have suitable housing, the guide will respawn.